# Change Alt +Dead Circumflex to switch between windows of the same Application

Tags: unity, unity-dash, application-switcher

On my german keyboard layout (in Ubuntu 15.10) there is no direct key for **Dead Circumflex**

How do I change this setting so I can switch between windows of the same Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In german layout you can switch between windows of the same application with  `ALT` + `^` which is right above the `TAB` key